# Which approach is best to unit test composed code?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

Say I have the following AngularJs service:

```
angular.module("foo")
    .service("fooService", function(){
        var svc = this;

        svc.get = function(id){...};
        svc.build = function(id){...};
        svc.save = function(thing){...}; //posts, then returns the saved thing
        svc.getOrCreate = function(id){
            return svc.get(id).then(function(thing){
                return thing || svc.build(id).then(function(builtThing){
                    return svc.save(builtThing);
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

I can unit test the `get` method by making sure the right API endpoint is being reached, with the right data.

I can test the `build` method by making sure it pulls data from the proper endpoints/services and builds what it's supposed to.

I can test the `save` method by making sure the right API endpoint is being reached.

What should I do to test the `getOrCreate` method?  I get two differing opinions on this:

1. stub the `get`, `build` and `save` methods and verify they're called when appropriate, and with the proper parameters
2. stub the API endpoints that are being called in `get` and `build`, then verify that the endpoints within `save` are being called with the proper parameters

The first approach is basically saying, "I know these three methods work because they're independently tested.  I don't care how they actually work, but I care that they're being called within this method."

The second approach is saying, "I don't care about how this method acts internally, just that the proper API endpoints are being reached"

Which of these approaches is more "correct"?  I feel the first approach is less fragile since it's independent of how the `get`, `build` and `save` methods are implemented, but it's not quite right in that it's testing the implementation instead of the behavior.  However, option 2 is requiring me to verify the behavior of these other methods in multiple test areas, which seems more fragile, and fragile tests make people hate programming.

This is a common tradeoff I find myself facing quite often with tests... anybody have suggestions on how to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to come down to a matter of opinion.

If you are unit testing your tests should work on very specific functionality.

If you start chasing promises, and you have promise chaining, where does it stop?

Most importantly, as your unit test scope gets bigger and bigger, there are more things that it depends on (services, APIs etc...), and more ways in which it can brake that may have nothing to do with the "unit". The very thing that you want to make sure works.

Question: If you have a solid controller that works great with your template, and a unit test that ensures your controller is rock solid. Should a twice detached promise that resolves from the response of a web service http API call break your controller test?

On the other hand, the same way you test your API client end points by mocking the service, you can test the service with its own tests using something like Angular's [$httpBackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpBackend) service.

Comment: I think I'm leaning towards mocking the `$httpBackend` for the `getOrCreate` method, but if a controller is consuming this service, then I'd clearly mock the service instead of mocking the underlying http calls.  How's that sound?

Comment: That sounds like a plan DMac. It's what I usually do. It's my own way of stubbing which makes for a more robust and less breakable unit test. I have enough code maintenance to do. I want to keep test maintenance to a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen it done both ways and don't have a strong preference either way.  Personally, however, I would consider option 1 where you don't mock the other functions that are tested elsewhere to be integration tests because they're calling multiple publicly visible functions and therefore would prefer option 2.